# How to delete emails stored locally on my MacBook pro?

Tags: mac, email

My system was running out of disk space so I checked and found out that Mail is occupying close to 3 GB of disk space. The Mail app is about 40 MB and the restare the files locally downloaded from the Mail. How can I delete these files without affecting the original mails?

Comment: Some mail servers can be set up to store all mail on the server and others allow the mail client to download a copy then delete it off the server. If you lose original mails matters exactly how your mail provider set things up. Can you check with each mail provider to be sure nothing is downloaded locally?

Answer (score 1):

What email is the Mail app using? If its not iCloud then you can easily manage how much email is sent to your Macbook directly from the clients website (Gmail, Yahoo, Aol, & etc). If it is iCloud email, then you may want to manage whats coming in. You can also turn mail off and on under iCloud in system preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Open System Information from the Utilities folder in /Applications. Choose the menu item Window → Storage Management, then choose Mail. Follow the instructions to remove downloaded attachments.

Comment: Followed along with what you recommended. There isn't really any option once I choose Mail from Storage Management. It just shows that the Mail is occupying 3GB of storage space. For other options for example the iOS files options it does show the option to delete those files but not for the Mail tab.